# Add more symbols to haskell `haskell-font-lock-symbols-alist`

Tags: elisp, font-lock, haskell-mode

I'm trying to add more symbols to `haskell-mode`'s `haskell-font-lock`.

The documentation for `haskell-font-lock-symbols-alist` says:

> Alist mapping Haskell symbols to chars. Each element has the form
>   (STRING . CHAR) or (STRING CHAR PREDICATE). STRING is the Haskell
>   symbol. CHAR is the character with which to represent this symbol.
>   PREDICATE if present is a function of one argument (the start position
>   of the symbol) which should return non-nil if this mapping should be
>   disabled at that position.

I'm trying something like:

```
(add-to-list 'haskell-font-lock-symbols-alist `("heart" . 2665))
```

But when typing 'heart' in haskell mode the font-lock won't work, although it works for `->`, `.`, `=>`.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important value at runtime is `haskell-font-lock-keywords`, which is generated from the alist when loading `haskell-font-lock.el`.  After changing `haskell-font-lock-symbols-alist` you will also have to recompute the value of `hakskell-font-lock-keywords`.

This snippet will add the heart character to the alist and recompute `haskell-font-lock-keywords` such that `heart` in a Haskell source file is rendered as   `♥`:

```
(eval-after-load 'haskell-font-lock
 '(progn
    (add-to-list 'haskell-font-lock-symbols-alist `("heart" . 9829))
    (setq haskell-font-lock-keywords
          (haskell-font-lock-keywords-create nil))))
```